# How to load a file from url and assign to HTML file upload on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the TUI Image editor API version.

https://nhn.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/tutorial-example02-useApiDirect

In this tool, we have an option named "Mask" where the user can select an image, and that image is displayed onto a canvas, its functionality is working fine.

Now I want to create another button like `<button id="loadImg"></button>`
and by clicking on this button the MAsk file uploader should load this image file to Canvas:

```
"https://editor.studysciences.com/img/shade1.png"
```

I don't want to browse it and then select the file. How to perform this using javascript?

Comment: why you deleted the question? The mentioned link is not an answer for my question. I am asking. How to get the image file from URL and assign this file to HTML file upload by clicking a <button id="apply"></button>

Comment: Brother at least ask me if you are not clear. I reposted the question. I hope it is clear now

Comment: Thanks. sure i do it

Comment: please allow my question now. I provided more details about m question. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217417/discussion-between-wedevelop-and-blex).